# how to update a list of React select

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to update a list from React select but it could not be updated, i dont know why it is happen, i think there is a problem in my handleChange() method but what is the problem i didn't getting.
thanks.!!

code:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Select from 'react-select';
   
class  extends countryComponent {
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              country:[],
            };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }

 handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
      
    });
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    await API.get("/country").then(response=>{
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({country:response.data.data.country});
  })     
 Country=()=>{  
  return (this.state.country.map(data => ({ label: data.name, value: data.id })))  
}    
     
    render() { 
        
        return ( <>

                            <Form.Group>
                                <Form.Label id="formLabel">Country</Form.Label>
                                <Select options={this.Country()}/>
                            </Form.Group>
</>)
}
export default Country;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are loading option asynchronously. Should use 'react-select/async' instead. Please refer https://react-select.com/async